# Reference Variable as a value - VB6

Tags: vb6

Is it possible to use a variable value as a name for a reference variable? For example:

```
Dim PersonName As String
PersonName = recordset("PersonName")
```

Instead of the value of PersonName being a person name e.g. JoeBloggs; the reference variable itself would be JoeBloggs i.e. joebloggs = whatever.

I have looked around for the answer as I thought it would be a common question; but I was unable to find one.

Comment: Why would this be common? This defeats the whole point of a variable—something whose value you don't know until run time!

Comment: Can you clarify your question some more. Perhaps with an example pointing out the value of each item at each step.

Comment: @Shane Wealti, I am trying to set the name of the reference variable dynamically at runtime. If this does not make sense then I will post some code. SLaks, why do I "want a dictionary"?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have a variable name that isn't known at compile time.

Comment: it makes no sense because at runtime your programming is dealing with pointers to memory locations where the contents of the variables are stored the names of the variables themselves are completely meaningless to the runtime.

Comment: @w0051977 dont worry, your need (if i understand it correctly) does make sense - i've posted an answer, if i've understood your question correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@w0051977 dont worry, your need (if i understand it correctly) does make sense, ive wanted to do this once as well. If you understand it, you want to be able to define your variables name using a string? Like, if you have a "JohnDoe" in your database then you want to set the name of your variable as a string named JohnDoe, am i right? if that is right, you can't directly do this in VB6, however, in vb.net we have reflection so there is some way you can read the name of the variable and have it returned as a string (though i understand you want to do the opposite). So, best way to do this in vb6 is the following...

```
Dim c As Collection ' where c is our collection to make it short-hand/less typing.
Set c = New Collection ' you could have done As New Collection instead but this is better, trust me.

c.Add "MyValue1", "JohnDoe" ' sets a variable named JohnDoe with value "MyValue1"
c.Add "MyValue2", "JessKay" ' remember, these are stored as Variants, but can use as string.
```

Now to call it...

```
MsgBox c("JohnDoe") ' this simple.
```

so c("JohnDoe") will return whatever is in the value you've set for this variable name.

same story for the chick, say you wanna set another variable with the girls value in it...

```
Dim abc As String
abc = c("JessKay") ' thats all :)  abc will equal "MyValue2"
```

Also, remember anything stored in a VB6 collection will always be stored as a Variant, so takes more memory than a String. However, you can still use it as a string or a number or anything else you want.

Cool?

Let me know if your needs were actually different and i've misunderstood your question. thanks.